# Foursquare: Search for "Uncategorized" venues

Tags: api, search, foursquare, categories

I'm trying to research some data about foursquare usage in my city, for which I need to compile a list of all the venues. The most reasonable way seems to be, to poll for venues in a ne,sw area by category and splitting it up in smaller ones, if I get 50 venues per category (which is the response limit).

Thing is, there are some venues with the category set to "Uncategorized". E.g. https://foursquare.com/v/fonzi/4e20f6af45dd950bb020b1c1

How can I poll for those? Setting `categoryId` to `Null`, `""` or `"Uncategorized"` didn't work.

I hope you can help :)

P.S. When doing a `venues/search` with `intent: "browse"`, do you also get venues which are outside your limits, if the area is very small? It appears so to me, but I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to filter your query to just uncategorized venues. Sorry!